# Upstream sent unsupported protocol version

Tags: symfony, ubuntu, nginx

I am trying to setup symfony on nginx.
Below are the configuration -

```
upstream phpfcgi {
        server 127.0.0.1:9000;
# server unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock; #for PHP-FPM running on UNIX socket
}
server{
  listen 80;
  server_name xxy.xxy.com;
  root /home/abcdef/website/current/web;
  location / {
  # try to serve file directly, fallback to rewrite
          try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
  }

  location @rewriteapp {
  # rewrite all to app.php
          rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php/$1 last;
  }

  location ~ ^/(app|app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
          fastcgi_pass phpfcgi;
          fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
          include fastcgi_params;
          fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
          fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
  }

  error_log /var/log/nginx/project_error.log;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/project_access.log;
}
```

I am getting this error

```
2013/12/12 11:23:55 [error] 25515#0: *5 upstream sent unsupported FastCGI protocol version: 60 while reading response header from upstream, client: 111.84.98.65, server: xxy.xxy.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "xxy.xxy.com"
```

Can somebody help me on this?

Comment: Check in /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf what port use php-fpm. May be there is another service running on this port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check

```
netstat -tap
```

to see if another application is listening on port 9000. If so try to kill it

```
kill -l PID
```

or change the port in your nginx config. Your error often happens when the configured port is already in use.

Comment: Thank you @artworkad. I solved it by switching to another port as port 9000 is already in used by another process.

Answer (score 0):

I have to do a server config when that issues to me too, in my experience I prefer to use a unix socket in a try to free the NAT, in another hand to run this is need to install fpm before, doing something like this:
`sudo apt install php5.3-fpm` that packet isn't included in phpX-common install, thank you.