# upstream sent unsupported FastCGI protocol version

Tags: wordpress, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I am trying to setup wordpress with mysql on nginx using docker-compose. Below are the configurations:

**nginx:**

```
server {
    server_name blog.site.com;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    root /srv/wordpress/data;


    location / {
        root /srv/wordpress/data;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    location /sitemap {
    rewrite ^/sitemap.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=1 last;
    rewrite ^/([^/]+?)-sitemap([0-9]+)?.xml$ /index.php?sitemap=$1&sitemap_n=$2 last;
    }
    location ~* \.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
    expires 1y;
    log_not_found off;
    root /srv/wordpress/data;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    location ~* \.(css|js|woff2|woff|ttf)$ {
    expires 30d;
    log_not_found off;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/font_err.log;
    root /srv/wordpress/data;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }
  
    location ~ \.php$ {
        error_log /tmp/php_nginx.log;
        root /srv/wordpress/data;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

**docker-compose:**

```
services:
   wpdb:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - /srv/db/wp:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: xxxxxxxxxx
       MYSQL_DATABASE: my_wp
       MYSQL_USER: xxxx
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: xxxxxxxxxx

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - wpdb
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "9000:9000"
     restart: always
     volumes:
       - ./data:/var/www/html
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: wpdb://wpdb:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: xxxx
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: xxxxxxxxxx
       WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: my_wp
```

but i am getting this error:

```
2020/07/18 09:40:15 [error] 7302#7302: *1 upstream sent unsupported FastCGI protocol version: 72 while reading response header from upstream, client: 213.217.43.162, server: blog.site.com, request: "GET /wp-admin/install.php?step=2 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "blog.site.com"
```

i see [Drupal Page returning 502 error page instead of 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53606945/drupal-page-returning-502-error-page-instead-of-404) and [Upstream sent unsupported protocol version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20535076/upstream-sent-unsupported-protocol-version) and some other solution about ports but they can't help me to solving this error

here is my result of `sudo lsof -i :9000`

```
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE   DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
docker-pr 2081 root    4u  IPv6 98062308      0t0  TCP *:9000 (LISTEN)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same error with the `wordpress:latest` Docker image. Changing it to `wordpress:5.1.1-fpm-alpine` fixed it for me.

If you need to debug more, a `docker ps -a` and `curl -L localhost:9000` is to check if the Wordpress container is actually running correctly. What is the output of those?

Also this DigitalOcean tutorial worked for me flawlessly: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-with-docker-compose